# Rotating UIImageView with tap of a button, each way?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiimageview

I've been searching for a solution to this..

I want to rotate a ImageView (45 degrees with each step) with the tap of a 
I want it to rotate each way, so if I tap two steps right, I want it to be able to tap two steps back a.s.o.

Can anyone help me with som code, tutorial, reference or documentation...?

Thank you so much in advance, you guys are always the best!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [CGAffineTransformRotate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation)

```
CGAffineTransform transform = imageView.transform;

// Rotate the view 45 degrees (the actual function takes radians)
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (M_PI / 4));
imageView.transform = transform;
```